# Do these hotkeys exist for Flash Pro CS6?

Tags: flash-cs5, flash-cs4, flash-cs6, flash-ide

1) when you are in edit mode for one symbol, go into edit for the next symbol in library

2) automatically put cursor in the instance name box for selected movieClip

As far as I know there are is no way to put shorcuts for moving around "inside of the library panel"

A duplicate and edit shortcut would sure be nice though. I can't even find where you would do it in custom shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

The examples you have listed do not have shortcut keys because they are not default tasks inside of the IDE.  That being said you can create ways to do those examples using JSFL to first create a command and then assign a keyboard shortcut to that command.  As an example I will include a script for the second item in your list.

> 2) automatically put cursor in the instance name box for selected
>   movieClip

There currently isn't a way to tell the IDE to send the cursor to the instance name box in the properties panel, but you can get around that by using JSFL.  Let's make our own instance name box pop up.

Here is the code required to do this:

```
// Assign Instance Name - Andrew Doll

/* This code will provide a prompt for the user to assign an instance name to a selected symbol on the stage. The great thing about using a
// prompt is that the focus is already in the input field of the prompt.  To speed up your workflow I recommend assigning a keyboard
// shortcut to this command.
*/

// Check to see if there is a file open first.
var dom = fl.getDocumentDOM();
if (dom == null)
{
    alert("Please open a file.");
}
else
{
    // Make sure to only select one symbol on the stage at a time.
    if (dom.selection.length > 1)
    {
        alert("You can only select one symbol to assign an instance name to. Please make only a single selection on the stage.");
    }
    // Make sure that you have at least one symbol selected.
    else if (dom.selection.length == 0)
    {
        alert("You need to select a symbol on the stage to assign an instance name.");
    }
    // Make sure that the symbol you have selected is a movie clip or a button.
    else if (dom.selection[0].symbolType == "graphic" || dom.selection[0].elementType != "instance")
    {
        alert("Your selection needs to be a button or a movie clip symbol.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Pop up a prompt for the user to assign an instance name with.
        var iName = prompt("Assign an instance name to the selected symbol.");
        // If the user cancels then do nothing.
        if (iName == null)
        {
            // Do Nothing.
        }
        else
        {
            // Assign the instance name to the selected symbol.
            dom.selection[0].name = iName;
        }
    }
}
```

Save this command as a JSFL script in the commands folder in your Flash config directory and then assign a keyboard shortcut to it.